# Prevent scroll when virtual keyboard appears

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, virtual

I have a trouble with IOS device such an Iphone. When i focus input(its inside fixed div) virtual keyboard display. However it's scroll whole viewport and position fixed div scrolls too. How to solve this ?

I've been researching many posts and forums

- [Research 1](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/issues/302)
- [Research 2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/issues/136)

What i want to:

**Position fixed div must stay at top**

**Prevent scrolling whole site when virtual keyboard appears**

**Allow scroll on search-result div**

My html:

```
<div class="header">
    <button type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>
    <div class="search"><!-- Its not visible until user click on search button -->
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search here"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my html and when i type something it suggests me some result based on my
keyword. And result will be appended into `DOM`.

```
<div class="search-result"><!-- Appended via javascript -->
    <ul class="suggest-list">
        <li>Some item of search result</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#searchButton", function(e){
    var field = $("#search"); // Gets the search input
    field.focus(); // Focus the input for virtual keyboard shows up

});

/* cache dom references */
var $body = jQuery('body');

/* bind events */
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function() {
    $body.addClass('fix');
})
.on('blur', 'input', function() {
    $body.removeClass('fix');
});
```

And the sass file:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dadce7;
    input {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       border: 0;
    }
}
/* Style of search result */
.search-result {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
/* Fix the layout */
body {
    &.fix {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed; // overflow will be work;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```